# Using mknod and device-cgroup-rule to dynamically pass a printer to a dockerized cups

Tags: linux, printer, docker, device-manager

I'm trying to use my Raspberry Pi as a print server for my printer by running a dockerized cups. Everything works just fine when I `docker run` my image passing in the printer with the `device` flag.

But, this being a home rather than an office printer, it's not always on. The [Docker create documentation](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/create/#dealing-with-dynamically-created-devices-device-cgroup-rule) seems to show how to deal with just that situation using the `device-cgroup-rule` flag in conjunction with `mknod`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

On the host, the printer has major/minor numbers 180/0. 
Following the instructions linked to above, I run the cups container using `device-cgroup-flag="c 180:* rmw"`, then inside the container do `mknod /dev/lp0 c 180 0`. But now running `lpinfo -v` still doesn't detect the printer, as I had expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...it seems to work when I put it under `/dev/usb/lp0` instead of just `/dev/lp0`.